# Spring data implemention for handling request with dates in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have an issue with spring data handling mongo db searches with a date range.

My spring data repository define a function with this signature :

```
long countByDatetimeBetween(ZonedDateTime start, ZonedDateTime end);
```

And in the logs, I can see that spring is sending the following request against my mongodb instance.

```
db.collection.find({ "datetime" : { 
 "$gt" : { "$date" : "2014-10-18T15:06:44.408Z"} , 
 "$lt" : { "$date" : "2014-10-25T15:06:44.408Z"}
}})
```

The problem is this request does not reply with any values. After some tests with mongo shell, i've noticed that the following syntax is working :

```
db.collection.find({ "datetime" : { 
 "$gt" : ISODate("2014-10-18T15:06:44.408Z") , 
 "$lt" : ISODate("2014-10-25T15:06:44.408Z")
}})
```

So my questions are :

- Is that normal that the $date operator does not behave as the ISODate syntax ?
- Is there a way to tell spring data to use the ISODate format instead of the date operator ?

Thanks for assistance.

**EDIT :  subset of data to show structure**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("549827e1dff2a4d24f5afb26"), "datetime" : ISODate("2014-11-02T21:39:06Z"), "origin" : "origin" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("549827e1dff2a4d24f5afb27"), "datetime" : ISODate("2014-11-13T04:57:32Z"), "origin" : "origin" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("549827e1dff2a4d24f5afb28"), "datetime" : ISODate("2014-11-26T03:56:29Z"), "origin" : "origin" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("549827e1dff2a4d24f5afb29"), "datetime" : ISODate("2014-11-16T04:47:17Z"), "origin" : "origin" }
```

**EDIT : mongo shell results**

```
> db.errors.find({ "datetime" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : "2014-10-18T15:06:44.408Z"} , "$lt" : { "$date" : "2014-10-25T15:06:44.408Z"}}})
> db.errors.find({ "datetime" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2014-10-18T15:06:44.408Z") , "$lt" : ISODate("2014-10-25T15:06:44.408Z")}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("549827e1dff2a4d24f5afb1f"),  "datetime" : ISODate("2014-10-24T14:33:54Z"), "origin" : "origin" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("549827e1dff2a4d24f5afb2a"), "datetime" : ISODate("2014-10-24T04:40:07Z"), "origin" : "origin" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("549827e1dff2a4d24f5afb6e"), "datetime" : ISODate("2014-10-25T02:17:47Z"), "origin" : "origin" }
>
```

Comment: The two forms are actually equal. Certainly for the shell but also under the MongoDB Java Driver the [extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) syntax is also valid, but really it's just serializing that way for reference.A valid `Date()` object is all you need. There is another reason this is failing that you are not diagnosing with the data here.

Comment: hello. thanks for comment. can you please check if you see something in the subset of data I've added in the post ?

Comment: I Can't really add anything other than to say that the data presented does not match the query. There is no result because nothing matches the conditions. Not within the date range specified.

Comment: I just sent a subset for you to see the data structure. These particular data does not match the query. In the db shell, when I run the ISODate syntax it works, the $data syntax does not.

Comment: Just saying it makes it hard to diagnose when you don't present data that makes a positive/false case. As it stands there is no obvious reason why this fails. So as I said. Something else is wrong. Up to you to provide the data or other information that disproves this.

Comment: mongo shell extract added to the post